# Weird assembly language addition bug

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, irvine32

I'm programming an implementation of the Fibonacci sequence in assembly language, and I'm getting a strange bug. It works at first, but when I reach 8+13 (that is, 8+D in hex) it gives me 15. I'm compiling/running this with the Visual Studio 10 / MASM 32

Here's my code (Irvine32 is a library with some utility functions in it), and then I'll explain the output I get when I run it:

```
TITLE Fibonacci 

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

.code


main PROC

mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx,12         ; set the loop counter to 12


    ;the 12 registry dumps display fib(1)-fib(12) in the eax register.
    ;As this is iteration based instead of loop based, the math comments
    ;in the loop are slighty off at the begining because of the edge condition
    ;so my comments about fib(n-1), etc. are valid only at fib(n) where n >= 2



 fib:   

    mov edx,eax  ;store fib(n-1) in a register temporarily
                 ;although the first time the loop runs,

    add eax,ebx  ;add fib(n-1) to fib(n-2) to get fib(n)
    mov ebx,edx  ;replace fib(n-2) with (fib n-1)

        ;at this point, eax holds fib(n), and ebx hold fib(n-1), which will be
        ;used to calculate fib (n+1) for the next loop iteration

    call DumpRegs

    loop fib

exit; exit the program
main ENDP

END main ; first procedure called is main
```

My `eax` register dumps from `DumpRegs` are, in order, 
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, D, 15, 22, 37, 59, 90

As you can see, this diverts from the correct Fib sequence where it is "D". So, how can I fix this, and more importantly, I want to understand what's happening here to cause this. Thanks!

edit: Alright, I see my silly mistake. Obviously all the output's in hex. Well, I guess this is just another reminder for me not to be hasty. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: show us the DumpRegs proc too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE REMARK:** *Your code works, you're confused only because most of the output doesn't result in hex letters and looks like decimals. 15H is 21D, which is the correct number.*

This should work:

```
    mov ax,0
    mov bx,1
    mov cx,12

  step:

    add ax, bx
    call DumpAX
    push ax ; or you can use DX to swap values of ax and bx - or xor op if you wish
    push bx
    pop ax
    pop bx
    loop step

    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

*All* your output is in hex. 0xD is 13,  0x15 is 21, 0x22 is 34 and so on. So the computation seems right, but your DumpRegs procedure is doing something weird.